# Big Query filtering null rows of Custom query creating table

Tags: google-bigquery, analytics, firebase-analytics

I am trying to query my data in big query and want to avoid null records but keep getting them.

Here is my query so far:

```
select 
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x 
WHERE x.key='restaurantName' 
and x.value is not null).string_value as restaurantName ,
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x 
WHERE x.key='restaurantId' and x.value is not null).string_value as 
restaurantID , 
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x 
WHERE x.key='user_id' and x.value is not null).string_value as user 
FROM some_data_set where event_name="ConfirmOrderBtn" and event_date between 
'20191110' and '_*' and app_info.id = "app_id"
```

Here are my query results:

[image: This is image to show query results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    (SELECT x.value 
      FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x 
      WHERE x.key='restaurantName' 
      AND x.value IS NOT NULL
    ).string_value AS restaurantName ,
    (SELECT x.value 
      FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x 
      WHERE x.key='restaurantId' 
      AND x.value IS NOT NULL
    ).string_value AS restaurantID , 
    (SELECT x.value 
      FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x 
      WHERE x.key='user_id' 
      AND x.value IS NOT NULL
     ).string_value AS user 
  FROM `project.dataset.some_data_set` 
  WHERE event_name="ConfirmOrderBtn" 
  AND event_date BETWEEN '20191110' AND '_*' 
  AND app_info.id = "app_id" 
)
WHERE NOT (restaurantName IS NULL OR restaurantID IS NULL OR user IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, adding a `WHERE` clause such as `WHERE restaurant_name IS NOT NULL` will stop rows with a null value in 'restaurant_name' from appearing in your results.

**Update**: Now I can see your query is pretty complex and using sub queries - if you want to filter our the null values form your end results, in this case, you could use `HAVING`, for example:
`HAVING restaurant_name` IS NOT NULL`

`HAVING` executes after your sub queries, so it acts link a final filter on results - note that you will still be charged for returning all the data before the `HAVING` clause.

Here is a link to the documentation on `HAVING`:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#having-clause

Hope that helps!

Comment: following is my query select
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key='restaurantName' and x.value is not null).string_value as restaurantName ,
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key='restaurantId' and x.value is not null).string_value as restaurantID ,
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key='user_id' and x.value is not null).string_value as user
FROM `some_data_set` where 
event_name="ConfirmOrderBtn"  and event_date between '20191110' and '_*' and app_info.id = "app_id"

Comment: Thank you for welcoming :) . Also i have added not null check in query but its still returning null records

Comment: Thank you, I have edited your question to add in this query and updated my answer accordingly!